# Displaying View with custom SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

So I am still new to MVC and SQL.
What I am trying to do is display an Employee's name (Employee.Name) rather than their ID (MovieEmployees.ID) on the Index view for Movies (i.e. localhost/Movies/)

I imported my database into SQL Express, I made the model for Movie and then did the auto-generate controller for the Views which made a (Create, Delete, Details, Edit, and Index View)

Here is my current MovieController's Index

```
 // GET: /Movies/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         return View(db.Movies.ToList());
    }
```

Here is the Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Entities.Movie>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.movieEmployeeID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.showID)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.movieEmployeeID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.showID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

And here is what displays right now
[image]

What I want is for the actual Name to appear and not the MovieEmployee's ID.

**How do I implement this correctly so that Index shows the Employee's Name and not their ID?**

Here is my database diagram that shows Employee.Name and MovieEmployees.ID within my Movies database
[image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Can you show us where you are populating your model? Also, I suggest you looking into viewmodels instead of strongly typing your entities to your views.

Comment: Hi! By populating do you mean where the data is coming from? If so that is already pre-entered. I am very new to MVC so I am interning right now for a company and they want me to practice on all sort of stuff. I started off with code-first, then MVC, then SQL, now I am using the SQL database I made with MVC. So everything was pre-made and I added that datamodel to this MVC. Does that help? If not please guide me in what you need me to do, thank you very much!

Comment: I see, in that case I would suggest you start with an empty MVC project and then watch / read some tutorials so you can get a better understanding of how .net MVC works. Then you would be able to do whatever you like, since you'd be writing code instead of using auto-generated code :)

Comment: Oh so I probably should remove the auto-generated stuff and write my own Index and such? I believe that is what I am building up too I am just afraid to dive into that this early on. I have been dabbling with MVC for about 40 hours now but it still seems like a lot to me.

Comment: I'm only suggesting starting from a blank slate would be a good learning process since you would have to write out all the code, which would hopefully lead to you learning what and why you're writing as you write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for accidentally hitting the Save too soon earlier.

Create a ViewModel like below:

```
 public class MovieViewModel
 {
      public int MovieId{get;set;} 
      public int ShowId{get;set;}
      public string EmployeeName{get;set;}
 }
```

Then in the controller,

```
 // GET: /Movies/
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     // the query can be better than this but just to get you started
     // you can also do db.MovieEmployees.Where and pass a predicate to filter results

     var model = db.MovieEmployees.Select(m=>new MovieViewModel{
                                    MovieId = m.Movie.ID,  
                                    ShowId= m.Movie.ShowId,
                                    EmployeeName = m.Employee.Name
                                  });

     return View(model);
 }
```

Then the view will be (trying to keep it simple),

```
  @model IEnumerable<MovieViewModel>
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }
 <h2>Index</h2>
 <p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
       <th>
           Employee Name
       </th>
       <th>
           Show ID
       </th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model) 
  {
    <tr>
      <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
      </td>
      <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShowID)
      </td>
      <td>
          @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.MovieId }) |
          @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.MovieId }) |
          @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.MovieId })
      </td>
   </tr>
  }
  </table>
```

Thus you are sending properties to the view that it needs with viewModel and nothing else. You can learn more about MVC on from [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started), [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals&highlight=), [MVCMusicStore Code](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) and [Rob Conery's spin on Music Store](https://github.com/tekpub/mvcmusic). There is plenty of material you can find on MVC by Rob Conery, Scott Hanselman, Jon Galloway, Phil Haack, Scott Guthrie, Brad Wilson and others.